# How do I remove a self ssl certificate on debian 8,?

Tags: ssl, certificate, debian, self, signed

I bought an ssl certificate and after installing it, it doesn't work. Support says i need to remove self signed certificate.

I'm running on debian 8, apache2. Company is ovh. Everything is inside a vps.

I've uploadd all the files where they should be and I have 3 sites configured at the same time with diferent domains using vhosts. I just want to install the certificate in one of them.

The thing is, anyways, how to remove this "self signed certificate".

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You would assign a new certificate to replace the current one.

If you were to remove it completely, then your connection wouldn't be using SSL encryption, instead you'll be using an HTTP protocol to communicate, and you don't need anything for that.